# Why is my component ref always undefined during test

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library, use-ref

I have a container element that renders a bunch of button components within it. One of the requirements I'm trying to implement is that in case only one button is rendered, I want it to be disabled. Now, the logic that determines how many buttons will be rendered within the container is quite complicated so I can't just check the `length` of a list to determine that.

So I thought I would be creative and use a ref to check how many children the container has to determine whether the button inside should be disabled:

simplified code snippet:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const isDisabled = !containerRef.current || ref.current.children.length < 2;

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      {roster.map((category) =>
        category.positions.every((position) => position.isSelected) ? (
          <Button disabled={isDisabled} {...otherProps} />
        ) : (
          category.positions.map(
            (position) =>
              position.isSelected && (
                <Button disabled={isDisabled} {...otherProps} />
              )
          )
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The above code works in my app but the problem is that when I'm trying to test this component, `ref.current` is always undefined which prevents me from testing the case where I have more than one button rendered in the container and that they are NOT disabled.

My test:

```
it('calls handleClick when a button is clicked', async () => {
    const { user } = render(
      <Component {...defaultProps} rosterPositionsConfig={config}/>
    );
    const firstButton = screen.getAllByRole('button')[0];
    await user.click(firstButton );

    expect(defaultProps.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); <-- assertion failing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first render of this component will **always** have undefined for containerRef.current, because the element on the page can't exist until after you've rendered.

So actually, the only reason your code is "working" is that your component is rendering twice (or more). The first render always has no ref and thus sets `isDisabled` to true, and the second one does have the ref and calculates `isDisabled` from that. I would guess that it's rendering twice due to `<React.StrictMode>`, in which case your code will stop working when you do a production build (strict mode causes a double render in dev builds only). In the test environment, you only render once, so this accidental double rendering goes away, and the bug becomes more apparent.

I recommend that you fix this by not using a ref. Instead, you can count the number of children from the data directly. There's a few ways this logic could look, but here's one:

```
const Component = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef();

  let count = 0;
  for (const category of roster) {
    if (category.positions.every((position) => position.isSelected)) {
      count += 1;
    } else {
      count += category.positions.filter(
        (position) => position.isSelected
      ).length;
    }
  }
  const isDisabled = count <= 1;

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      {roster.map((category) =>
        category.positions.every((position) => position.isSelected) ? (
          <Button disabled={isDisabled} {...otherProps} />
        ) : (
          category.positions.map(
            (position) =>
              position.isSelected && (
                <Button disabled={isDisabled} {...otherProps} />
              )
          )
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you don't like the fact that this is basically writing the same looping logic twice (i'm not a fan of that either), here's another way you might do it. You create an array of buttons assuming that they will not be disabled, but then if the length is 1, you use cloneElement to edit that JSX element:

```
import { cloneElement } from "react";

const Component = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const isDisabled = !containerRef.current || ref.current.children.length < 2;

  // I'm building the array this way so that it's just a 1-d array, and it
  //   doesn't have any `false`s in it
  const buttons = [];
  roster.forEach((category) => {
    if (category.positions.every((position) => position.isSelected)) {
      buttons.push(<Button disabled={false} {...otherProps} />);
    } else {
      category.positions.forEach((position) => {
        if (position.isSelected) {
          buttons.push(<Button disabled={false} {...otherProps} />);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  if (buttons.length === 1) {
    buttons[0] = cloneElement(buttons[0], { disabled: true });
  }

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      {buttons}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you absolutely had to use a ref (which, again, i do not recommend for this case), you would need to wait until after the render is complete for the ref to be updated, then count the children, then set state to force a second render. You would probably need to use a layout effect so that this double render doesn't cause a flicker to the user:

```
const Component = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setDisabled(containerRef.current.children.length < 2);
  });

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      {roster.map((category) =>
        category.positions.every((position) => position.isSelected) ? (
          <Button disabled={isDisabled} {...otherProps} />
        ) : (
          category.positions.map(
            (position) =>
              position.isSelected && (
                <Button disabled={isDisabled} {...otherProps} />
              )
          )
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you for the detailed explanation. I actually already have a solution for figuring out whether only 1 button is rendering using array methods. I just thought it is much more straight forward and less code to go with the children/ref approach. I tried implementing your solution using `useState` and `useLayoutEffect` but the ref still remains `undefined` in my tests :(

Comment: I can see the component in the test re-rendering as I get multiple console.logs printed out, but the ref remains `undefined` even after those additional renders